# Partial derivative of double summation mixing rule

Tags: derivatives, summation

I am trying to derive the expression for fugacity for a Van der Waals gas using the fundamental thermodynamic equations. I have encountered a problem in trying to calculate the partial derivative of a double summation mixing rule as follows:

$$
an^2 = \sum_i\sum_j n_in_j(1-k_{ij})\sqrt{a_ia_j}
$$
I know from the Prausnitz molecular thermodynamics text that the derivative for a simpler expression is as follows:
$$
an^2 = \sum_i\sum_j n_in_j\sqrt{a_ia_j}
$$
$$
 \frac{\partial{(an^2)}}{\partial{n_i}} = 2\sqrt a_i\sum_jn_j\sqrt a_j
$$

However, when I take the derivative of the expression involving the constant $k_{ij}$ I get the following:
$$
\frac{\partial{an^2}}{\partial{n_i}} = 2an_i(1-k_{ii})\sum_jn_j(1-k_{ij})\sqrt{a_j}
$$

Wondering if anyone has insight into a more clear, systematic way to take a partial derivative of a double sum. NOTE: $a_i,a_j,k_{ij}$ are all considered to be constants and $n$ is the total number of moles and therefore also a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the partial derivative of $an^2$ with respect to the variable $n_{i_0}$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\left(an^2\right)}{\partial n_{i_0}}
=\frac{\partial}{\partial n_{i_0}}\sum_{i}\sum_{j}n_in_j(1-k_{ij})\sqrt{a_ia_j}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

**Note:** We should avoid using the same variable name for different purposes. Since $i$ is used as bounded index variable on the RHS, we should not use $n_i$ as variable for the partial derivative on the LHS.

> In order to calculate the partial derivative of double sums we have to do some bookkeeping by *explicitely* considering the parts of the double sum where the indices $i,j$ are equal with $i_0$.
>
> Using for convenience the shorthand $A_{i,j}:=(1-k_{i,j})\sqrt{a_ia_j}$,  we obtain from (1)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial\left(an^2\right)}{\partial n_{i_0}}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial n_{i_0}}\sum_{i}\sum_{j}A_{i,j}n_in_j\\
> &=\frac{\partial}{\partial n_{i_0}}\sum_{i\neq i_0}\sum_{j\neq j_0}A_{i,j}n_in_j
> +\frac{\partial}{\partial n_{i_0}}\sum_{i= i_0}\sum_{j= i_0}A_{i,j}n_{i}n_{j}\\
> &\qquad+\frac{\partial}{\partial n_{i_0}}\sum_{i= i_0}\sum_{j\neq i_0}A_{{i},j}n_in_j
> +\frac{\partial}{\partial n_{i_0}}\sum_{i\neq i_0}\sum_{j= i_0}A_{i,j}n_{i}n_{j}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{\partial}{\partial n_{i_0}}\sum_{i\neq i_0}\sum_{j\neq i_0}A_{i,j}n_in_j
> +\frac{\partial}{\partial n_{i_0}}A_{i_0,i_0}n_{i_0}^2\\
> &\qquad+\frac{\partial}{\partial n_{i_0}}\sum_{j\neq i_0}A_{{i_0},j}n_{i_0}n_j
> +\frac{\partial}{\partial n_{i_0}}\sum_{i\neq i_0}A_{i,{i_0}}n_{i}n_{i_0}\tag{2}\\
> &=0+2A_{i_0,i_0}n_{i_0}+\sum_{j\neq i_0}A_{{i_0},j}n_j+\sum_{i\neq i_0}A_{i,{i_0}}n_{i}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j}\left(A_{i_0,j}+A_{j,i_0}\right)n_j\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}

**Comment:**

- In (1) we split the double sum in portions according to $i_0$ equal to $i,j$ resp. not equal to $i,j$.
- In (2) we do some simplification. In fact (1) is only written for demonstration and we could start the apportionment with (2) instead.
- In (3) we do the partial differentiation and rearrange the terms in (4)

> If we substitute for $A_{i,j}$ back we obtain finally
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j}&\left(A_{i_0,j}+A_{j,i_0}\right)n_j\\
> &=\sum_{j}\left((1-k_{i_0,j})\sqrt{a_{i_0}a_j}+(1-k_{j,i_0})\sqrt{a_ja_{i_0}}\right)n_j\\
> &=\sqrt{a_{i_0}}\sum_{j}\left(2-k_{i_0,j}-k_{j,i_0}\right)n_j\sqrt{a_j}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* If $k_{i,j}=0$ for all $i,j$ we obtain from (5) in accordance with OPs example 
\begin{align*}
2\sqrt{a_{i_0}}\sum_{j}n_j\sqrt{a_j}
\end{align*}